# Converting std::string to Unicode String in c++

Tags: c++, string, unicode, c++builder

I have a problem. I need to convert string type to unicode.
I know metod like

```
string.c_str();
```

but it doesn't work in my code.

I have function

```
void modify(string infstring, string* poststring)
```

and in it i need to display infstring in memo. Like a

```
Form1->Memo1->Lines->Add("some text "+infstring.c_str()+" some text");
```

but compiler says me "E2085 Invalid Pointer addition"

How can i solve my problem?

Comment: now it says "Cannot convert 'string' to Unicode string". I think, that ss.str() returns string type, but i need in unicode string. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean "Unicode String"? That's not a C++ type, what type do you mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Form1->Memo1->Lines->Add("some text "+infstring.c_str()+" some text");
```

should be

```
Form1->Memo1->Lines->Add(("some text "+infstring+" some text").c_str());
```

i.e. you add the string literals to the `std::string` *then* use `c_str()` to get a `const char*` from it.

That still won't work if the `Add()` function takes a different type, but you haven't given enough information to know what you're asking about.

Comment: The OP is most likely using C++Builder (the syntax matches its VCL UI framework), in which case an alternative would be this: `Form1->Memo1->Lines->Add("some text " + String(infstring.c_str(), infstring.length()) + " some text");` The VCL's `String` class (uppercase `S`), which `Add()` takes as input, accepts a `char*` and optional length in its constructor, and can be concatenated with `char*` values to create temporary `String` instances.

Answer (score 3):

use a stringstream

```
#include <sstream>
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "some text" << mystring << "some text";
Form1->Memo1->Lines->Add(ss.str().c_str());
```